# как связать две view in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, view

Доброго дня, извиняюсь за повторение вопроса... Как связать две въюшки? в смысле у меня две въюшки: 1-я блок а вторая - страница(каталог), выводят они поля одного типа материала (блок 6 штук а на странице один пост и постраничная навигация), как сделать кнопочку просмотреть что бы при нажатии я переходил на страницу с этим постом... Пример: у меня блок на главной и пост (пусть будет фильм "Матрица") на главной он в списке 3-й и при нажатии мне нужно перейти на ту страницу каталога где есть детальное описание (например в каталоге это страница 4). P.S Сделать нодами и выводить тизеры на главной не могу так, как все должно быть в каталоге с возможностью перейти на следующий фильм... Буду очень признателен ели есть какой-то обходной путь...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как связать два views drupal 7](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576827/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-views-drupal-7)

Comment: это был мой вопрос, я решил перезадать вопрос с лаконичной формулировкой и поднять его заново)) спасибо за внимательность))

Comment: Для этого достаточно было отредактировать тот вопрос, он автоматически поднимается с новой "лаконичной формулировкой"

Comment: я здесь новичок) буду знать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, проблему лучше решать с другой стороны - все-таки вывести через ноды, а затем добавить кнопочки «Вперед» «Назад» в ноде. Для последнего подойдет модуль https://www.drupal.org/project/views_navigation. Страницы в этом модуле можно сортировать и фильтровать.
Кроме очевидной простоты, есть еще один плюс этого метода с точки зрения SEO — ссылки на фильмы будут постоянными, не зависящими от прибавления и удаления в списке элементов.

Comment: Спасибо) сейчас попробую

Comment: Спасибо, всё ок)

Comment: Извините, а вы не подскажите, можно ли там сделать такую навигацию http://prnt.sc/cw95qz?

Comment: К сожалению, я использую drupal 8, а этот модуль под 7

Comment: тогда дальше буду что-то думать, спасибо вам большое, очень выручили!)